# Solr boosting and '~' character

Tags: solr

I would like to know, what does the '~' character mean in the following `Solr` query snippet:

```
... q="field:'value'~30^10 ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~` is used to do Fuzzy search in this case.
the fuzzy query is based on Levenshtein Distance algo. This algo identifies minumun number of edits required to covert one token to another.

this is the syntax that is used:

> q=field:term~N

where N is the edit distance. The value of N varies from 0 to 2.

If you do not specify anything for N, then a value of 2 is used as default.

N=2 -> This matches the highest number of edits.

N=0 -> This means no edit and would have same effect as term query.

You can give a fraction value between 0 and 1 but any fraction value greater then 1 will throw the following error.

```
org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Fractional edit distances are not allowed!
```

Note: However giving a fraction values less then 1 also defaults to 2.

so  `q=field:term~0.2` will have the same effect as `q=field:term~2`

Also any distance greater then 2 will also default to 2.
so in the following case

> q="field:value~30"

is same as  (you can verify this by looking at debug query.)

> q="field:value~2"

which will match the highest no. of edits.

Note:
the tilde in the fuzzy query is different then the proximity query. In a proximity query the tilde is applied after the quotation mark.
e.g below query

> q=field:"foo bar"~30

So in your case when you are adding quotes around the field

```
q="field:'value'~30"
```

it is becoming proximity search, which really applies if you have two terms in the field. So it wont do much instead of just finding docs which have "value" set in "field".

Comment: Are you sure about that? When using `"` or `'` around the term phrase search is invoked automagically here on our 4.10.2 installation (and I don't remember the basic syntax changing for this). The hits returned for `field:"value"~2` is the same as for `field:"value"`, while the hits returned for `field:value~2` includes fuzzy matches as well.

Comment: Yes. so `field:"value"~2` or `field:'value'~2` will invoke proximity search and since there is only single term here it becomes trivial to just `field:"value"~2. However if we do not add quotes then it becomes fuzzy search. I think in my answer i added the single quotes without realizing. Thanks for pointing that out. I will update the answer.

Comment: Yes - but the question has the single quotes (.. and a regular quote before the field name, which is .. weird - but lets ignore that for now), and thus, is a phrase search, not a fuzzy search.

Answer (score 2):

In your example it means nothing - but if there were multiple words in your query, i.e. `"foo bar"~30`, it would mean "find foo and bar within 30 positions of each other". It allows you to give a phrase match a margin in regard to how close each term has to be to each other.

The `^10` part is telling Lucene how much to weight the phrase match compared to other parts of the query.

From [the Lucene Query Parser Syntax description](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html):

> Lucene supports finding words are a within a specific distance away. To do a proximity search use the tilde, `"~"`, symbol at the end of a Phrase. For example to search for a `"apache"` and `"jakarta"` within 10 words of each other in a document use the search:
>
> `"jakarta apache"~10`